# How to inject spring managed service beans to Apache CXF Servlet

Tags: spring, web-services, dependency-injection, cxf

I am trying to develop a web service using Apache CXF and using Spring to manage the beans. annd jetty as my web server.

So here is my Resource/WebService class

```
   import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    @Path("/test")
    public class TestService{

        @GET
        @Path("/add/{name}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String showName(@PathParam("name") String name){
            return name + "";
        }


    }
```

My Web.xml

```
<!-- Bean Declarations -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/test-beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And test-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.ws" />

</beans>
```

How would I then integrate my Spring manage Service bean with Apache CXF as a Rest web service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a namespace to your's Spring config file:

```
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
```

and also schema location for it:

```
 http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
```

Also you are going to need some dependencies for CXF Rest web service:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
   <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And then configure your JAX-RS server in your Spring config something like this:

```
 <jaxrs:server id="yourJaxRsServer" address="/testService">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
       <ref bean="serviceBean"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
 </jaxrs:server>

 <bean id="serviceBean" class="service.TestService"/>
```

Don't forget to remove `@Component` annotation from your `TestService` class as you are declaring it in `.xml` config. Or if you want to keep this annotation for better view add a name to it `@Component("testService")` and then you can remove `<bean id="serviceBean" class="service.TestService"/>` declaration from `.xml` and change reference to be `<ref bean="testService"/>`.

More information you can find at:

- [JAX-RS : Services Configuration](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html)
- [JAX-RS (JSR-311)](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html)

Comment: how would I access my service then? given the project name is spring-cxf and the cxf servlet is configured as /api/* ?

Comment: Can you provide info on how to register the service using Spring Java Config?

Answer (score 1):

To access your web service, you need to hit following URL

```
http://<HOST>:<PORT>/<Application Context>/testService/api/test/add/<NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD>
```